# Find the transition density of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

A scalar diffusion $X=(X_t)_{0\leq t \leq T}$ is the unique strong solution of the SDE
$$\text{d}X_t=\text{d}W_t$$
where $W=(W_t)_{0\leq t \leq T}$ is a scalar Brownian motion.

Assume that the state space of $X$ is $R$. Let $Y=(Y_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be given by $\text{d}Y_t=\text{d}t$.

Define $p(x,y;t)\text{d}t:=P(Y_{\tau}\in \text{d}t|X_0=x,Y_0=y),  \tau:=\text{inf}\{t\ge 0:X_t=m\}$

Find $p(x,y;t)$.

I'm only vaguely familiar with stochastic processes, should I use Kolmogorov forward equation or backward equation to solve it?

Comment: Essentially you need to compute the density of the distribution of $\tau$. Ever heard of the reflection principle (for Brownian motion)?

Comment: @saz Yes. I know the density of the first hitting time of Brownian motion. Is it $p(x,y;t)$?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments, this is simply the density for Brownian motion

$$p(x,y;t)\text{d}t:=P(Y_{\tau}\in \text{d}t|X_0=x,Y_0=y)=P[y+\tau\in dt| X_{0}=x].$$

This has been computed here [Density of first hitting time of Brownian motion from its CDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409333/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-from-its-cdf).