# Density of first hitting time of Brownian motion from its CDF

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $T_a$ be the first hitting time of level $a$ for standard Brownian motion. I am trying to show the density of $T_a$ is $f_a(t)=   \frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}\text{exp}(-\frac{a^2}{2t})$

I know that $\mathbb{P}[T_a \leq  t ] = 2\mathbb{P}[B_t \geq a]$ where $B_t \sim N(0,t)$ (standard brownian motion)

I have reduced this to: $F_a(t) = 2 \Phi(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}})$ where $\Phi$ denotes the cumulative density of the standard normal RV.

I did not have much luck with [differentiation under the sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) (aka Leibniz rule)

Is there a simple transformation that is more fruitful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your CDF is slightly wrong $P(T_a \le t) = 2 P(B_t \ge a) = 2 \Phi(-a/\sqrt{t})$.

Applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus yields
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left[2\int_{-\infty}^{-a/\sqrt{t}} \phi(u) \, du\right]
= 2 \phi(-a/\sqrt{t}) \frac{d}{dt} (-a/\sqrt{t})
= at^{-3/2} \phi(-a/\sqrt{t}).
$$

Comment: I cannot express my gratitude :))))))))))))))))

Comment: And correct me if im wrong but the trick here, the reason that it is so much easier your way was the fact that we removed $t$ for the integrand and then then didn't need to compute another integral ?

Comment: @OskarSzarowicz There should be no $t$ in your integrand; think carefully about what $\Phi(-a/\sqrt{t})$ means. I suspect this error is why you thought you had to use differentiation under the sign, when it is actually unnecessary.

Comment: I did not use $\Phi$ at all. I had left the entire thing in terms of the non-standard normal distribution of $B_t$ and hence had $t$ in the integrand.

Comment: @OskarSzarowicz But you eventually [mistakenly] arrived at $\Phi(-a/t)$ (which has no $t$ in the integrand), did you not?

Comment: I attempted the problem with two methods. Firstly involving $t$ in the intergrand without the use of $\Phi$ which required diffention under the sign. I then secondly arrived at the incorrect version with $\Phi$ Thanks again for your help :)